# Support for macOS framework includes in VSC?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have the following code:

[image: Code]

This code will compile and run without any trouble. However, Visual Studio Code does not recognize the CoreFoundation import. I have attempted to place various paths like "/System/Library/Frameworks" in my includePath and browse:path in the c_cpp_properties.json file, but it does not resolve the problem.

I am guessing it is because VSC does not support or recognize macOS framework includes.

What I am wondering is if there is something I can do so that VSC would recognize a macOS framework include.

Comment: have you installed C/C++ extension?

Comment: Yes, I have installed that extension.